# Use of something like $group inside $addFields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is one of my document from collection `movies`:

```
{
        "_id" : 4,
        "startYear" : 1892,
        "title" : "Un bon bock",
        "originalTitle" : "Un bon bock",
        "rating" : 6.4,
        "type" : "short",
        "numVotes" : 105,
        "genres" : [
                "Short",
                "Animation"
        ]
}
```

I would like every document to have a field called `normalizedRating` that is calculated as follows:

```
normalizedRating = (rating - min(rating)) / (max(rating) - min(rating))
```

So, I get document like:

```
{
        "_id" : 4,
        "startYear" : 1892,
        "title" : "Un bon bock",
        "originalTitle" : "Un bon bock",
        "rating" : 6.4,
        "type" : "short",
        "numVotes" : 105,
        "genres" : [
                "Short",
                "Animation"
        ], 
        "normalizedRating": 6.3
}
```

I am able to get the above result by using two different queries. I'm curious to know if it can be done using a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You wanted to do it in one query, then try either one of these two :

**Query 1 :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "",
      maxRating: { $max: "$rating" },
      minRating: { $min: "$rating" },
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data",
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.normalizedRating": {
        $divide: [
          { $subtract: ["$data.rating", "$minRating"] },
          { $subtract: ["$maxRating", "$minRating"] },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" },
  },
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XQvrX2rLFi1)

**Query 2 :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      data: [{ $match: {} }],
      ratingValues: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "",
            maxRating: { $max: "$rating" },
            minRating: { $min: "$rating" },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data",
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$ratingValues",
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.normalizedRating": {
        $divide: [
          { $subtract: ["$data.rating", "$ratingValues.minRating"] },
          { $subtract: ["$ratingValues.maxRating", "$ratingValues.minRating"] },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: { ratingValues: 0 },
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" },
  },
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YZ2IYl-5L0F)

At end of the day if your dataset is medium one then these can perform good, but on huge datasets these might or might not work well - I would say to split this task into two to do some work in code or multiple calls if really needed or try to implement the same task using [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/index.html) if aggregation is really slow.

Comment: Thanks @whoami both queries perform good on my data set. I just found the first query more relevant as I have never used `$facet` before.